# What's best practice for configuring logs of Spring Boot app running on ECS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We have a suite of *microservices* that are currently hosted on AWS [ECS-Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/). They are implemented using Spring Boot and packaged as a Docker container using an OpenJDK-based image.

Application logging is configured using `logging.config` from the Spring runtime [core properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#core-properties) and currently points to a bundled classpath resource as follows:

```
logging:
  config: 'classpath:config/logback-spring.xml'
```

At the ECS task level we configure logs using the *awslogs* driver which redirects all console output to AWS CloudWatch.

However, this approach is quickly proving unwieldy as it requires us to rebuild and subsequently redeploy the microservices everytime we need to modify the logging configuration.

What is the current best practice for configuring logs using resources external to the application when hosted within the AWS environment?

Comment: did you find a solution? :) facing the same problem

Comment: I am yet seeking for a good solution.. for now we are setting up logging configuration from SSM parameters via `spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config` and restarting services as needed. i.e.

`logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient: debug`

Comment: Maybe you can think about a Sidecar?